# multiple filters on table NOT to over ride but to overlap

Tags: javascript, jquery

You have always been great help sp thank you all for that. Here's my problem.

I have a working example here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hvYzwoxMUQq1Z3veFagT?p=preview

You can see that the first select filters my table on the 2nd column and the second select filters my table on the 4th columns. My problem is that they over ride each other. For example if I first select "John" in the first select.. the table will show me the 3 Johns ... but when I then select "apple" in the second select it will show me all 4 people with apple as fruit... and I would like it to show the 2 John's with apple.

```
$(document).ready(function($) {


$('#mySelector_f_name').change( function(){
  var selection = $(this).val();
  $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

  if (selection) {
    $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
      $(item)[$(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
  }

});
});

$(document).ready(function($) {


$('#mySelector_fruit').change( function(){
  var selection = $(this).val();
  $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

  if (selection) {
    $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
      $(item)[$(item).find('td:nth-child(4)').is(':contains('+ selection  +')')? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
  }

});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

https://plnkr.co/edit/lows7kDId5jK8tpgvzxf?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function($) {


    $('#mySelector_f_name').change( function(){
      var selection = $(this).val(),
          anotherDropdownSelect = $('#mySelector_fruit').val();

      $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

      if (selection) {
        $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
          var isShowOrHide = $(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').is(':contains('+ selection  +')') &&
                             (anotherDropdownSelect ? $(item).find('td:nth-child(4)').is(':contains('+ anotherDropdownSelect  +')') : true);
          $(item)[isShowOrHide ? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
      }
    });
});

$(document).ready(function($) {


    $('#mySelector_fruit').change( function(){
      var selection = $(this).val(),
          anotherDropdownSelect = $('#mySelector_f_name').val();

      $('table')[selection? 'show' : 'hide']();

      if (selection) {
        $.each($('#myTable tbody tr'), function(index, item) {
          var isShowOrHide = $(item).find('td:nth-child(4)').is(':contains('+ selection  +')') &&
                             (anotherDropdownSelect ? $(item).find('td:nth-child(2)').is(':contains('+ anotherDropdownSelect  +')') : true);
          $(item)[isShowOrHide? 'show' : 'hide']();
        });
      }

    });
});
```

What I did is, took another variable which will look for another dropdown, and using combination, I am showing results

**Update**

The best way to handle this kind of situation is to disable the option, so that user cannot select it like

```
<option value="" selected disabled>Please Select</option>
```

But if you want that to be selected and do filteration then you can do something like this

https://plnkr.co/edit/cjH45e7nTcHWraxv6xHo?p=preview

Comment: Mr. Kenny, sir :) you seem to be a ninja at this. Can you please taka another quick look here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Mgn6dgvvxHx8hcRkYlW6?p=preview
how could I make it so that when I select "ALL EMPS" or "ALL FRUIT" that filter "drops" but the other is still filtering

Comment: Kenny Sensei ! A thousand "thank you verymuch"s. If I could be so bold and ask you one last thing on this code. See, in your last updated plnkr if I select John it shows me all Johns, if I also select 'apple' it shows me all John's with apples, ... if i select 'please select' in the first select , it shows me all people with apples ... so it works fine until this pint becasue if I select 'please select' in the second select ( so in both) it displays nothing... and it should display all. Help me Obi Wan Kenny-bi, you're my only hope

Comment: For this you need to comment the line in which you are hiding your entire table